# Swift Shrink Animation

Tags: swift, animation

I think this should be a simple question to answer, but I haven't been able to find a solution yet.

All I want is an animation that shrinks a view from its original size to a smaller size.

I have tried this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(10.0, animations: {
    self.view.frame = CGRectInset(frame, 0.2 * frame.width, 0.2 * frame.height)
})
```

This does shrink the view, but it abruptly blows it up before shrinking it then only shrinks it back to its original size.

I have also tried this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(10.0, animations: {
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01)
})
```

But this has the same problem as the first option, although it does shrink it down to a smaller size than the original size after blowing it up.

**How can I create an animation that shrinks a view from its original size to a smaller size?**

Comment: you can use CABasicAnimation and scale your view.layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into CABasicAnimation as recommended by Leo Dabus, I was able to solve my problem. Here is some simple code that shrinks a view (stored in the variable "view") from its original size to a smaller size (100x smaller):

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
var tr = CATransform3DIdentity
tr = CATransform3DScale(tr, 0.01, 0.01, 1);
animation.toValue = NSValue(CATransform3D: tr)
view.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "transform")
```